# Extracting parts of a list subject to a condition

Tags: list-manipulation

I've got a list like following:

```
{{{x1,y1,1}, {x2,y2,1}, {x3,y3,1}, {x4,y4,1}, {x5,y5,1}}

{{x6,y6,2}, {x7,y7,2}, {x8,y8,2}, {x9,y9,2}, {x10,y10,2}}

{{x11,y11,3}, {x12,y12,3}, {x13,y13,3}, {x14,y14,3}, {x15,y15,3}}}
```

What I want to do:

Choose out of every row the triplet with the highest x value. Then, out of these triplets, choose the one with the lowest x value.

Comment: Don't use formatting commands like `Grid` to initialize lists, see bullet point 6 [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395).

Comment: Hi ! Please, visit the help centre and read more about proper code formatting. Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: The question is not completely clear (for a start you have triplets `{x,y,z}` where `y` is actually `x`...) Are you just looking for the triplet with the most negative value of `z`?

Comment: can you provide an actual numerical example, along with the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use a $m\times n\times3$ array of random numbers as input:

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 10, 3}];
```

The following finds the maximum (by first element) of each row, and then finds the minimum (by first element) of the result:

```
MinimalBy[MaximalBy[#, First] & /@ list, First]
```

producing (for my random numbers)

```
{{{0.741714, 0.438475, 0.85645}}}
```